# Include Facebook comment wall in a native android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I'd like to have a facebook comment wall in my native app.

Facebook Android SDK doesnt seem to have this, so my only option is to use the web social plugin? Should I use it in a webview? But that means that even if I use Facebook login in my app there will be two sessions (one for my app, and one for the plugin)?

So my question in short, can I have a facebook-style comment wall without a webview?

Answer (score 0):

The facebook comment plugin is only available for web.
Comment feature not included in Facebook Android SDK.